# Запуск функции из другого класса и передача значений меток между разными формами

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2, pyside6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как по нажатию кнопки на одной форме запустить функцию, описанную в другом классе?

Я использую PySide6. Есть главная форма, с которой вызываются дополнительные.

Открываю форму `SaleForm`, на ней расположена кнопка оплаты `pushButton_3`, нажимая на которую открывается форма `PayForm`.

Вопросы:

1. Как передать с формы `SaleForm` текст из `TextLabel` (`self.label_8 = QLabel(Dialog_Sale)`) в `TextLabel` на форме `PayForm` (`self.label_2 = QLabel(self.groupBox)`)
2. Нажав на кнопку на форме `PayForm` (`self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(...)`) запустить функцию
   `check_ticket_generate()` из класса `SaleForm`

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в данной проблеме.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Главная форма"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        """Открыть окно добавления нового клиента"""
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openClient)
        """Отображение всех клиентов"""
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.buttonAllClient)
        ...
        self.ui.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(self.openSale)

    def openSale(self):
        """Открываем форму с продажей"""
        sale = SaleForm()
        sale.button_all_clients_to_sale()
        sale.show()
        sale.exec_()
```

Другой класс, который открывает дополнительную форму продажи. В нем выполняются основные вычисления.

```
class SaleForm(QDialog):
    """Форма с данными клиента"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog_Sale()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.openPay)
        self.ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.del_selected_item)
        self.ui.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.add_client_to_sale)
        cur_today = date.today()
        self.ui.dateEdit.setDate(cur_today)
        self.ui.checkBox_2.setChecked(Qt.Checked)
        self.ui.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.edit_sale)


    def check_ticket_generate(self):
        """Сохраняем данные данные заказа"""
        sale_tuple, tickets = self.edit_sale()
        state_check = kkt.check_open_2(sale_tuple)
        price = 0
        """Если прошла оплата"""
        if state_check == 1:
            """Сохраняем данные о продаже"""
            session = Session()
            add_sale = Sale(price=int(self.ui.label_8.text()),
                            id_user='1',
                            id_client=sale_tuple[5])
            session.add(add_sale)
            session.commit()
            session.close()
         ...   


    def openPay(self):
        """Открываем форму оплаты"""
        pay = PayForm()
        pay.show()
        pay.exec_()
```

А это форма оплаты.

```
class PayForm(QDialog):
    """Форма оплаты"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog_Pay()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect()
```

И запуск главной формы.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()

    auth = AuthForm()
    auth.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Внешний вид форм]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Как передать с формы SaleForm текст из TextLabel (self.label_8 = QLabel(Dialog_Sale)) в TextLabel на форме PayForm (self.label_2 =
>    QLabel(self.groupBox))
> 2. Нажав на кнопку на форме PayForm (self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(...)) запустить функцию
>    check_ticket_generate() из класса SaleForm

```py
class SaleForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # Передаем текстовое значение из метки
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.ui.openPay(self.ui.label_8.text()))

    def openPay(self, txt):
        """Открываем форму оплаты"""
        pay = PayForm()
        # Передаем текст в форму PayForm
        pay.setText(txt)
        # При нажатии на кнопку на форме PayForm в SaleForm 
        # запустится метод генерации чека
        pay.startGenerate.connect(self.check_ticket_generate)
        pay.exec_()

...

class PayForm(QDialog):
    startGenerate = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # Посылаем сигнал генерации чека
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startGenerate.emit)
    
    # Устанавливаем текстовое значение в метку
    def setText(self, txt):
        self.ui.label_2.setText(txt)
```

**Дополнение.**

Закрыть PayForm можно так:

```
class PayForm(QDialog):
    startGenerate = Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # Посылаем сигнал генерации чека
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.emitAndClose)
    
    def emitAndClose(self):
        self.startGenerate.emit()
        self.close()
```

Закрыть SaleForm можно так:

```
class SaleForm(QDialog):

    def check_ticket_generate(self):
        ...
        if state_check == 1:
            ...   
        accept() # или reject(), или close() смотрите документацию для QDialog
```

**Можно сделать "более логично"**. Дело в том, что вызов диалога через `QDialog.exec_()` подразумевает возврат и обработку значения целого типа ( в частности [QDialog.DialogCode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum)), но кроме этого можно возвращать и свои данные. Например:

```
# Тип платежа (перечисление)
class PaymentType:
    ByCard = 101
    ByCash = 102

class PayForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # при вызове done() окно должно закрыться и exec_ вернет переданный аргумент из done()
        self.ui.pushButtonByCash.clicked.connect(lambda: self.done(PaymentType.ByCash))
        self.ui.pushButtonByCard.clicked.connect(lambda: self.done(PaymentType.ByCard))
```

Тогда вызов PayForm в SaleForm будет выглядеть так:

```
class SaleForm(QDialog):

    def openPay(self, txt):
        """Открываем форму оплаты"""
        pay = PayForm()
        # Передаем текст в форму PayForm
        pay.setText(txt)
        res = pay.exec_()
        # если пользователь нажал крестик или кнопку Escape,
        # то по-умолчанию возвращается QDialog.Rejected
        if res == QDialog.Rejected:
            # наверное, надо ничего не делать в этом случае и 
            # просто завершить работу функции
            return
            # или закрыть SaleForm при помощи вызова reject()
 
        # иначе, если оплата выбрана
        if res == PaymentType.ByCard:
            # Оплачено картой
        else if res == PaymentType.ByCash:
            # Наликом

        # Генерируем чек
        self.check_ticket_generate()
        # Закрываем окно продажи и возвращаем QDialog.Accepted
        self.accept()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Единственное о чем сразу не подумал - после отправки сигнала генерации чека логично будет закрыть окно PayForm.

Comment: Закрыть PayFormможно вторым действием на одной и той же кнопке:
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startGenerate.emit)
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
Хотя, наверное, это не правильно. А вот как закрыть еще и другое окно SaleForm?

Comment: @MarcusStill дополнил

Comment: Большое спасибо! Классное дополнение.