# Из одного модального окна я вызываю второе и при нажатии на кнопку хочу чтобы данные (текст) с одного окна переносились в другое. Спасибо

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=MyWin):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.modal = Ui_Form_2()
        self.modal.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(2)
        self.modal.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.num)

    def num(self):
        wind_n = Num(self)
        wind_n.show()

class Num(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.m = Ui_Form_N()
        self.m.setupUi(self)
        # self.setWindowModality(2)
        self.m.pushButton_14.clicked.connect(self.push)


    def push(self):
      .........................
```

Comment: user483483, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Похожая "трудность" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1369229/235611